# Bottom border not overriding top border

Tags: html, css

I am building a series of tabs for a screen the div on the left behaves differently to the div on the right in terms of the top border.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have an unordered list (ul) on top of two divs which lay side by side which act as two columns.  To aid presentation I have a top border of the two divs to give the user the impression that this is the content.  To aid presentation even more I set the bottom border of my active tab to white so it appears that underneath the tab there is no border & the tab and the content area are the same space.  The problem I am having is that the bottom border of the tab overrides the right column but not the left but on the right the top overrides the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/z39zV/

You will have to adjust the screen size to get the screen to display the problem because one of the requirements is to have an expanding right column.

I have tried this in IE, Chrome & FF & they all display the same thing.  The left column has a float left so its probably something to do with that but I can't work out what!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the position property of the unordered list to relative so that it gets placed farther up in the stack. Here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/z39zV/4/

I would also suggest moving the border from the a elements to their parent li elements, and wrapping the two lower divs in a single div that has a complete border.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z39zV/1/

You weren't floating both columns, that was the main problem:

```
   .column_container_left {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        border-top:thin solid grey;                    
        border-bottom:thin solid grey;    
        border-left:thin solid grey;
        background-color: white;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .column_container_right {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        border-top:thin solid grey;                    
        border-bottom:thin solid grey;    
        border-right:thin solid grey;
        background-color: white;
        height: 500px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, unfortunately that has broken my auto expanding right column which for my page is a necessity.

Comment: Then remove the width attribute from the column_container_right element.  Either way, you need a float:left on the column_container_right column to fix your initial problem.

Comment: Removing the width attribute makes the column shrink.  I can't seem to achieve both requirements, at the moment it's one or the other.

Comment: You want your 1st column to be fixed and the 2nd column to be fluid? Is that right?  What is the width of your website?  You can use a min-width / max-width or a combination to possibly achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Yup, 1st column fixed, 2nd column fluid.  I achieved this with two overlapping divs, one with a fixed width floated to the left and the other one that would expand to the width of the page but with a left margin for where the other div would go.  I have tried max-width & min-width with the float attribute but when you float the div then seems to shrink. http://jsfiddle.net/hilladrian/z39zV/3/